# Inconsistent Loading Times for GeoRSS Overlay Between Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, rss, mapping, geolocation, yahoo-maps

I have a very simple page built to display a map and overlay a line based on
points in a GeoRSS XML file. Here is the publicly accessible file.
http://68.178.230.189/georssimport.html

Firefox is loading in about 5 secs, which is expected because there are a lot of
points to map, but IE (6 & 7) is taking upwards of 45 secs to a minute. What can I do to diagnose what is going on?  What is a tool that will show me what is going on? (i.e. Firebug for IE)

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: IE 7 and 8 are both taking that long?

Comment: My IE7 on Vista freezes on that site ;]
To many DOM objects I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Google Maps v3.  The polyline api worked great and consistently across all browsers.  A year later all of my posts to yahoo's developer forums are still unanswered.  I would not build on the yahoo Maps library, based on this experience.

Answer (score 0):

For IE6/7 you can try the [YUI Profiler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/). IE8 has one built in: Tools -> Developer Tools -> Profiler -> Start profiling -> Reload page

Comment: I installed IE8 on a clean VM and the profiler shows a 23 sec wait time as it calls into the yahoo library.  There's be no feedback on the yahoo maps user group.  Most questions there are going unanswered, with little to no feedback at all from the Yahoo Engineers.

Comment: I had similar problems with vector grapics in OpenLayers about a year ago, and it turned out to be the string concatenation for building up the VML-content that was slowing things down in IE. Since this probably is something happening inside the API it's not much you can do about it. Have you considered using another map API? For instance Google Maps:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geoxml-rss.html